# (дообучение chatGPT) Как правильно реализовать поиск в google документе?

Tags: python, google-docs, chatgpt, chatgpt-api

Пытаюсь дообучить ChatGPT на своей базе - искать информацию в гугл документе и выдавать точный ответ в формате диалога. Я пишу - найди мне "дополнительные требования к участникам", а он мне выдает тест из закона.
Вот код:

```
import requests
import re
import openai  

# Установите ваш ключ API от OpenAI
openai.api_key = 'токен'

# Функция для загрузки содержимого документа и выполнения поиска
def search_in_google_docs(url, search_query):
    # Извлечение идентификатора документа из URL
    match = re.search(r'/document/d/([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)', url)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError('Недопустимый URL Google Docs')
    doc_id = match.group(1)

    # Загрузка содержимого документа как обычного текста
    response = requests.get(f'https://docs.google.com/document/d/{doc_id}/export?format=txt')
    response.raise_for_status()
    document_text = response.text

    # Выполнение поиска в тексте
    if search_query in document_text:
         return f"Текст '{search_query}' найден в документе:\n{document_text}"
    else:
         return f"Текст '{search_query}' не найден в документе."
 
 # Функция для выполнения диалога с пользователем с использованием ChatGPT
def chat_with_user():
     while True:
         user_input = input("Вы: ")
         if user_input.lower() == 'выход':
             break
 
         # Вызов ChatGPT для ответа на запрос пользователя
         response = openai.Completion.create(
             engine="text-davinci-002",
             prompt=f"Пользователь: {user_input}\nМашина:",
             max_tokens=50
         )
         machine_response = response.choices[0].text.strip()
 
         # Вывод ответа машины
         print(f"Машина: {machine_response}")
 
         # Проверка, содержит ли ответ машины информацию о поиске
         if "Поиск в документе:" in machine_response:
             # Извлечение запроса на поиск из ответа машины
             search_query = re.search(r'Поиск в документе: (.+)', machine_response).group(1)
             # Вызов функции поиска в документе
             search_result = search_in_google_docs(google_docs_url, search_query)
             # Вывод результата поиска
             print(search_result)
 
 # Пример использования
google_docs_url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C7TisPMD2Bx_yjGsoRWbXBzTAUUf4P8eiofYTQZhhH8/edit'
 
print("Добро пожаловать! Введите 'выход', чтобы завершить.")
chat_with_user()
```

Пример:

Я пишу: найди мне дополнительные требования к участникам закупки.

ChatGPT: 2. Правительство Российской Федерации вправе устанавливать к участникам закупок отдельных видов товаров, работ, услуг, участникам отдельных видов закупок дополнительные требования, в том числе к наличию (...) ч.2 ст. 31 44 ФЗ.

Ссылка на документ - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C7TisPMD2Bx_yjGsoRWbXBzTAUUf4P8eiofYTQZhhH8

П.С. Я новичок в Питоне, но мне очень нужно реализовать поиск по документу, чтобы chatGPT выдавал информацию, а не просто ответ (т.к. в законе одинаковые термины повторяются много раз). Надеюсь на помощь.